# Dynamic consuming of web API in Django based on user's choice

Tags: python, django, api

The program I am trying to write requires that whenever the user changes a value in a form on Django website, that value will be written to the variable and then inserted into the API's url as parameter inside requests.get() function in views.py file.

So basically my Django website is to consume web API.

API returns different data sets ​​depending on the explicit endpoint. It can change dynamically depending on what the user chooses in a form, and then, if submit button is clicked, show the content on a django website immediately.

Here is the Web API which I use to get data sets:
http://api.nbp.pl/en.html

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    my_date_field = forms.DateField(widget = DateInput)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests


from .forms import ExampleForm


def home(request):

    submitbutton = request.POST.get("submit")  # I check if submit button is clicked
   
    form = ExampleForm()
    
    date2 = ''
    
    if form.is_valid():
        date2 = form.cleaned_data.get("my_date_field")  # write date choosen by user to variable
        
    # And now I have a problem. I want to use the value of this variable to specify an endpoint:
    
    response = requests.get(f"http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/a/2012-01-01/{date2}/")
    Api = response.json()

    context= {'form': form, 'submitbutton': submitbutton, "Api": Api}
        
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

The user selects a date in the form and based on that date, the data set is returned.

I have no problem with the HTML template file. I know how to insert form and submit button on a website, and how to view the data set using API, but my goal is to make it flexible - dependent on form value.

Current code returns error: JSONDecodeError. The help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check the response, see if it actually is a JSON response.

Comment: @NavidZarepak localhost:8000 informs me that there is no GET data, so probably it's not JSON response. How can I fix it?

Comment: Check the final URL and try it in your browser. see if there is any data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, URL constructed using the f-string returns data.

I found that if I don't use the function is_valid(), form is invalid but code returns correct reponse (Response [200]) and as a result the data is correctly displayed without error, but this only happens if the value of date2 is constant - this is not what interests me, I want it to be taken from the form!

Please have someone look at my code and say if I am doing something wrong, I am tired of this problem...

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

from .forms import ExampleForm


def home(request):

    submitbutton = request.POST.get("submit") 
    
    date2 = '2020-01-17'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExampleForm(request.POST)  
        
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Is Valid")                                                      
            date2 = form.cleaned_data.get("my_date_field") 
            date_string = str(date2)
            argument = f"http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/a/2012-01-01/{date_string}/"
            response = requests.get(argument) 
            Api = response.json()   # This causes an error, because response is incorrect, I don't know why
            
            return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form, 'submitbutton': submitbutton, "Api": Api} ) 
    else:
        print("Is no valid")
        form = ExampleForm()
    
    date2 = '2012-01-10'
    
    response = requests.get(f"http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/a/2012-01-01/{date2}/")
    
    Api = response.json()   # This doesn't cause an error, response is correct - but that way value of variable is not taken from the form...
    
    context= {'form': form, 'submitbutton': submitbutton, "Api": Api}
        
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```